# App.config XML transform from NuGet Package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuspec

I am attempting to follow [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/source-and-config-file-transformations#xml-transforms) to perform a simple XML transform on a target App.config file via a custom NuGet package.

The `app.config.transform` file contains the following content:

```
<configuration>
  <appSetttings>
    <add key="foo" value="bar" />
  </appSetttings>
</configuration>
```

The `.nuspec` file contains the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Foo.Bar</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>Foo Bar</title>
    <authors>Foo</authors>
    <description>Bar</description>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="app.config.transform" target="content" />
  </files>
</package>
```

This correctly inserts the file into the `content` folder in the `.nupkg` file when running `nuget pack`.

In Visual Studio 2017 (15.6.4) when adding the NuGet package to a brand new Console Application with an existing vanilla `App.config` file, no transforms take place (i.e. the content of `App.config` is unchanged). This is also the case with XDT transforms.

Can anybody advise why the transformation fails to take place?

**UPDATE**

I am using PackageReference as my package management format in the target .NET Framework 4.7.1 project.

Comment: Full gist [here](https://gist.github.com/WolfyUK/786e16352d29f2be79adc1cc14ff465b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Visual Studio 2017 (15.6.4) when adding the NuGet package to a brand new Console Application with an existing vanilla App.config file, no transforms take place.

What do you mean "*no transforms take place*"? The new elements and attributes under the `appSetttings` section not merged into the `App.config`?

I have created the nuget package with your `.nuspec` and `app.config.transform` files:

nuget package: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai1sp_yvodHf1QFNsI3ybdw2nanD

Then set it to my local feed, create a new .net console application and add that nuget package to the test project, you will find the new elements and attributes under the `appSetttings` section are merged into the `App.config`, so the `App.config` would be like this after install that nuget package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" />
    </startup>

   <appSetttings>
    <add key="foo" value="bar" />
   </appSetttings>

</configuration>
```

[image]

So it should be works fine. One possibility is you have not clean the cache when you install this package, to confirm this, please delete the packages folder under the solution folder.

**Note:**

Notice that NuGet didn't replace the `startup` section, it just merged the new entry into it by adding only new elements and attributes. NuGet will not change any existing elements or attributes.

**Update:**

> This does not work for me when performing exactly the same steps as you, but I am using PackageReference instead of packages.config. Is this a bug with PackageReference?

Not, it is not a bug with `PackageReference`. According to doc [Transforming source code and configuration files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/source-and-config-file-transformations#xml-transforms), the top two lines:

> For projects using packages.config, NuGet supports the ability to make transformations to source code and configuration files at package install and uninstall times. Only Source code transformations are applied when a package is installed in a project using PackageReference.

We could to know packages.config support the ability to make transformations to source code and configuration files, **However**, **Only Source code transformations are applied to the `PackageReference`**. That is reason why you could not get that work with `PackageReference`.

Comment: This does not work for me when performing exactly the same steps as you, but I am using `PackageReference` instead of `packages.config`. When switching back to `packages.config` this does indeed work as it has done for you. Is this a bug with `PackageReference`?

Comment: @WolfyUK, Not, it is not a bug with `PackageReference`.  That because only Source code transformations are applied to the `PackageReference`, it not support transforming configuration files currently. Check my updated answer for details.

Comment: Thanks. I have found a sample way of achieving transforms for `PackageReference` with MSBuild targets on [NuGet Samples](https://github.com/NuGet/Samples/tree/master/XDTransformExample)

Comment: @wolfyuk that sample was made to work but looks like it does not work for me. No transformation takes place at all.